# Como mostrar el contenido de un mensaje soap enviado desde un cliente axis a un servidor axis 1.4?

Tags: java, axis

En el lado del cliente (sistema) envió un mensaje xml al servidor para capturar los datos y a la vez el mensaje lleva archivos.

Al hacer el envió desde el cliente al servidor, axis proporciona su debug para mostrar el contenido que esta enviando. que es el siguiente:

```
      POST /axis/services/SubmitBookPort HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<DB7C8614B66A819F14D4487C00986E56>"; boundary="----=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256"
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Host: localhost:8888
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 12441
  
 
------=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <DB7C8614B66A819F14D4487C00986E56>
  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <submit xmlns="">
      <title>J2EE Web services</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
      <pdfDoc href="cid:98D5324BDADA66D7C30F64152EF86F76"/>
    </submit>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
------=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <98D5324BDADA66D7C30F64152EF86F76>
  
%PDF-1.2
...
%%EOF
  
------=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256--
```

como podran ver axis desde el cliente me muestra el tipo post:

```
POST /axis/services/SubmitBookPort HTTP/1.0
```

El content type:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<DB7C8614B66A819F14D4487C00986E56>"; boundary="----=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256"
```

y así sucesivamente.

y al final se agregan los archivos, no estoy seguro que tipo de codificación se usa. Solo lo agrego de la siguiente manera al _call:

```
_call.addAttachmentPart(dataHandler);
```

Ya al enviar el mensaje xml al final del xml aparece esta parte:

```
------=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: <98D5324BDADA66D7C30F64152EF86F76>

%PDF-1.2
aqui va codificado, no lo pongo porque es mucho texto..
%%EOF

------=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256--
```

Por ultimo  cuando se envía el mensaje, se carga todo el contenido que mostré al principio, diciendo axis que esto va enviar tal cual.

Ahora ese mismo formato que envía axis desde el cliente quiero imprimirlo tal cual en el servidor para ver si trae el mismo formato.

lo único que me muestra axis en modo debug del lado de receptor es esto:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <submit xmlns="">
      <title>J2EE Web services</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
      <pdfDoc href="cid:98D5324BDADA66D7C30F64152EF86F76"/>
    </submit>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

y no me muestra los AttachmentPart.

he usado los métodos que trae axis para extraer todo el contenido de la solicitud pero no he tenido exito.

La forma en que obtengo pedazos de la solicitud es la siguiente:

```
MessageContext msgContext = MessageContext.getCurrentContext();
```

El metodo `messageAttachments.getAttachmentCount()` solo me trae la cantidad de archivos recibidos.

El Metodo `messageAttachments.getContentType()` Me obtiene esto: `multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<DB7C8614B66A819F14D4487C00986E56>"; boundary="----=_Part_0_26644003.1204264500256"`

Regresando a mi pregunta. Como puedo obtener todo el contenido original que se envía desde el cliente y recibirlo tal cual en el receptor?

Comment: Siempre será mejor no dividir la atención creando duplicados de la misma pregunta inicial. Editar una pregunta y mejorarla siempre dará mejores resultados. Por ejemplo, ahora sí incluiste algo de lo que intentas para leer los datos del mensaje recibido.

Comment: Tienes código, tienes unos mensajes de error, dices que funciona local pero en otro lado no funciona... hay un montón de info que no nos comentas y nos tienes adivinando. Mientras no formules una pregunta que podamos responder en vez de adivinar, no vas a recibir ayuda útil. Saludos.

Comment: No amigo, es que ni siquiera hay mensajes de errores, para mi tambien es de estar adivinando que esta pasando, no se si es el servidor donde esta montando, o algun firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Revisar el SOAPenvelope (que es lo que está pintando el log de axis) no va a mostrar nada porque en el envelope no van los adjuntos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para acceder a los adjuntos, debería usarse algo similar a

```
java.util.Iterator iterator = message.getAttachments();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    AttachmentPart attachment = (AttachmentPart)iterator.next();
    String id = attachment.getContentId();
    String type = attachment.getContentType();
    System.out.print("Attachment " + id + " has content type " + type);
    if (type.equals("text/plain")) {
        Object content = attachment.getContent();
        System.out.println("Attachment contains:\n" + content);
    }
}
```

Pero no hay mucha certeza porque añades DOS líneas de tu código (como para ponernos a adivinar) y ninguna definición del web service, como para saber qué estás consumiendo y cómo. Revisa la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnbhf/index.html) de SAAJ para que revises qué es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Pero saaj y axis son diferentes no? Porque estoy ocupando axis. y quiero recibir ese mensaje completo porque he tenido problemas cuando envio archivos. Desde local funciona bien pero al subirlo a un servidor de desarrollo el receptor manda un error general que tampoco puedo saber que esta pasando y mi idea fue hacer un receptor y verificar que los xml se estan enviendo de forma correcta. Quisiera mostrar mi wsdl pero no puedo. Igual gracias